# RSpec - Converting Before(:each) do to :let

Tags: ruby, rspec

As  i read through guides they say i should use :let rather than before(:each) do while testing.

How do i convert these to :let?

```
    before(:each) do

      @book1111 = Book.new('1234','title 3','author 3', 23.99, 'Ruby', 5 )
      @memcached_mock = double()
      @database_mock = double()
      @target = DatabaseWithCache.new @database_mock, @memcached_mock 

   end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let(:book1111) { Book.new('1234','title 3','author 3', 23.99, 'Ruby', 5 ) }
let(:memcached_mock) { double() }
let(:database_mock) { double() }
let(:target) { DatabaseWithCache.new database_mock, memcached_mock }
```